# Restart e2e tests when one condition fails

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

> I am writing e2e test for signup process of a health website. Before signup there is a trial registration process for exclusion or inclusion of the user in the study. I have to write a test case where the user is excluded from study and then, browser restarts and user again fills up all the questionnaire and is included for study. Since the user has to answer same set of questions tests are same. So, is there a way I can redirect driver to restart all the tests.

protractor.conf.js

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
      'chromeOptions': {
        'prefs': {
          'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 1}
      }
  }
  ],
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

app.e2e-spec.ts

```
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should show login dialog', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.sleep(1000);
    page.clickBurgerBtn();
    browser.sleep(3500);
    page.clickLoginLink();
    browser.sleep(2500);
    expect(page.getTextOnLoginDialog()).toEqual('Not a member yet? Join the study');
  });

  it('should click on study and fill trial registration form', () => {
    page.clickSignupLink();
    browser.sleep(1500);
    page.fillSignupForm();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    page.fillTrialRegForm();
   //user gets excluded
    browser.restart();
   // restart tests 
   // user gets included
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put it block in for loop to execute twice.

```js
describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  for(let i=0;i<2;i++) {
    describe('Execute block of code twice', function() {
        it('should show login dialog', () => {
          page.navigateTo();
          browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
          browser.sleep(1000);
          page.clickBurgerBtn();
          browser.sleep(3500);
          page.clickLoginLink();
          browser.sleep(2500);
          expect(page.getTextOnLoginDialog()).toEqual('Not a member yet? Join the study');
        });

        it('should click on study and fill trial registration form', () => {
          page.clickSignupLink();
          browser.sleep(1500);
          page.fillSignupForm();
          browser.sleep(2000);
          page.fillTrialRegForm();
         //user gets excluded
          browser.restart();
         // restart tests 
         // user gets included
        });
    });
  }
});
```